# Cannot run apt update on debian:bullseye on armv7 because the time is not set corectly

Tags: linux, docker, debian

This works with `debian:latest`, but my issue is that I require glibc 2.29 or higher, which this does not provide. When I use `debian:bullseye`, and I try to update, I get the following:

```
root@d96ef2e6eeb8:/# apt update
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease [123 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease [40.1 kB]
Get:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease [44.1 kB]
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Err:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I assume that this is because of

```
root@adb7b60e4bfd:/# date
Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 UTC 1970
```

however, I cannot set it up correctly:

```
root@41e9609d3b81:/# hwclock --hctosys
hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.
```

Is there an image that is known to work correctly on armv7, and has glibc 2.29 or higher; or alternatively, is there a fix to the problem with this image?

Comment: time is used to measure the time is takes to execute a process and not the actual time on the system. To change the time, you will need to use the date command. Besides, where does it advise of an issue with the time?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it. It shows 1970. I assumed that the timestamp was the issue, as I also have it on different containers and can't find a fix :(

Comment: ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com

If you have ntp installed, syncing from a network time server is done like this.

Comment: I see the same issue but the date is correct. I feel it's unrelated to the problem.

Comment: I see. Any ideas how to solve it though?